# WSO2 integration with third-party SAML2 Service Provider

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm trying to configure third-party **SAML Service Provider** with **WSO2 Identity Server** acting as **IdP**.
I faced some problems which I believe may be connected with WSO2 implementation.

After a quick research I found that `AuthRepons`e sent by **WSO2IS** with `POST` binding is deflated and then `base64` encoded. It makes `AuthnResponse` unparseable to my SP. I checked the SAML spec which states that it should be only `base64` coded.

Another issue is that the **WSO2IS** requires `RelayState` to be sent with `AuthnRequest`. Otherwise an error is reported and request is not processed further. According to **SAML** spec this parameter is optional.

Are there any workarounds to get it working together other than customizing the SP implementation?

Comment: I have a similar issue, and I noticed the deflate + base64 is only an issue in 4.1.0.  4.0.0 doesn't have the problem.  No workaround... Sorry.

Comment: Both these issues are fixed in the latest release: IS 4.5.0

Comment: Have you check this with the latest release of the wso2 IS? If not please try this in wso2 IS 5.0.0 and you can download the pack from [here](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/)